# What do you call somebody who believes in Eastern pantheistic monism?

Tags: synonyms

As part of a paper on the New Age movement, I need to discuss Eastern pantheistic monism. Insofar as I can tell, the technical term for somebody who adheres to this worldview is "Eastern pantheistic monist". However, that is too verbose for my tastes.

Is there any more concise synonym I could use instead?

Comment: If that's what it is, that's what it is. We ain't got no special word for it. Not for Northern monotheistic dualism, neither.

Comment: This does seem to be the usual term. Rather than repeatedly type the whole thing, you could drop "Eastern" in subsequent usages, unless you're also discussing Western pantheistic monism (which afaik is less of a thing). Or use a three-letter acronym, or invent another term of your own (but be sure to define it).

Comment: What about "holistic approach"?

Comment: @StuartF but a problem there is that the New Age movement eschews Western values, and terminology, despite there being "nothing new under the sun". They must arrive at age-old conclusions by an indirect route.

Comment: How could 'pantheistic' anything equate to any kind of 'monism'? Doesn't (any)theistic deal with gods?

'Monism' might claim that only one supreme being exists… and equally, deny the existence of a distinction or duality in a particular sphere, such as that between matter and mind, or God and the world.

Which are you looking at, please?

Comment: You say that this is a technical term. This implies that there is a body of literature in which it is used as a technical term. You should handle the matter in whatever way it is handled in that literature.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "Atman is Brahman." According to Eastern pantheistic monism, there is one impersonal god which *is* the universe. As a corollary, its devotees deny the reality of the "real" world; everything is a manifestation of the One, and anything which appears to not be part of the One is "maya" (illusion).

Comment: @The Daleks Why would we not simply call such a one an 'Eastern pantheistic monist'?

If that's not appropriate, how is the Question about Language rather than for instance, Philosophy or Religion?

If you try to apply the detail cited in your last Comment, what barriers stand in your way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a word currently does not exist. "Eastern pantheistic monism" is by necessity so many words to explicitly express what the subject matter is or what is being talked about.

You can coin a new term to mean "Eastern pantheistic monism" subject to wide acceptance of this newly coined term.

You can also workaround the problem of too many words by shortening "Eastern pantheistic monism" (God it's really mouthful) to EPM by putting it in parentheses like this "Eastern pantheistic monism(EPM)" and later on only using EPM.